Need help in rewriting query
I have 2 databases test1 and test2. where I need to compare columns from schema1 to schema2 and fetch the results.If table in test1 schema not present on test2 schema ,it should ignore that table. I have below query which shows all the results including table not present in test2 schema.
select * 
from (
        select COALESCE(c1.table_name, c2.table_name) as table_name,
               COALESCE(c1.column_name, c2.column_name) as table_column,
               c1.column_name as test1,
               c2.column_name as test2
        from
            (select table_name,
                    column_name
             from information_schema.columns c
             where c.table_schema ='test1') c1
        right join
                 (select table_name,
                         column_name
                  from information_schema.columns c
                  where c.table_schema ='test2') c2
        on c1.table_name = c2.table_name and c1.column_name = c2.column_name

    union

        select COALESCE(c1.table_name, c2.table_name) as table_name,
               COALESCE(c1.column_name, c2.column_name) as table_column,
               c1.column_name as test1,
               c2.column_name as test2
        from
            (select table_name,
                    column_name
             from information_schema.columns c
             where c.table_schema ='test1') c1
        left join
                 (select table_name,
                         column_name
                  from information_schema.columns c
                  where c.table_schema ='test2') c2
        on c1.table_name = c2.table_name and c1.column_name = c2.column_name
) tmp
where test1 is null
      or test2 is null
order by table_name,
         table_column;

Is it possible to rewrite above query ,just compare table in test1 with test2 and display the mismatch columns.if table not present in test2 schema, it should ignore that table.
Thanks

test this:
WITH 
cte1 AS (
    SELECT table_schema,
           table_name,
           column_name
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_schema IN ('test1', 'test2')
    ),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT table_name
    FROM cte1
    WHERE table_schema = 'test2'
    )
SELECT table_name,
       column_name
       CASE SUM(RIGHT(table_schema, 1))
       WHEN 1 THEN 'Present in test1 only'
       WHEN 2 THEN 'Present in test2 only'
       WHEN 3 THEN 'Present in both schemas'
       ELSE        'Something went wrong..'
       END
FROM cte1
NATURAL JOIN cte2
GROUP BY 1, 2
/* ORDER BY ??? */;


let me try,thanks

The answer was updated, check that you test the actual version.

For starters, simplify
            from  
            (
                SELECT  table_name, column_name
                    from  information_schema.columns c
                    where  c.table_schema ='test1'
            ) c1
            left join  
            (
                SELECT  table_name, column_name
                    from  information_schema.columns c
                    where  c.table_schema ='test2'
            ) c2  ON c1.table_name = c2.table_name
              and  c1.column_name = c2.column_name 

to:
            from       information_schema.columns c1
            left join  information_schema.columns c2
                ON   c1.table_name  = c2.table_name
               and   c1.column_name = c2.column_name 
            where  c1.table_schema ='test1'
              AND  c2.table_schema ='test2'

